defining a base value for objects referenced in an optional step of a method claim
Method claim:

A computer implemented method comprising:
a. identifying a first score for a first user;
b. identifying a second score;
c. optionally identifying a third score;
d. identifying a first reward for the first user equaling the first score minus the second score; and
e. sending the reward to the first user on the condition that the reward is greater than the third score,
wherein any unidentified scores have a base value of zero.

This is just an example claim. The point is, I just need to know whether this claim can be rejected on indefiniteness caused by the optional step (c) to identify a third score. I want to know whether the wherein clause suffices to make the third score well defined, even in the implementations that do not identify the third score.
Questions:

would this trigger an indefinite rejection?
is this claim valid?
the step where the reward is sent to the user is valid for both when the third score is identified and not identified. when it is not identified, the wherein clause specifies that it shall have a base value of zero.


Please relabel the steps with lower case letters.

@GeorgeWhite done


I just need to know whether this claim can be rejected on indefiniteness caused by the optional step to identify a third score. I want to know whether the wherein clause suffices to make the third score well defined.

First of all, your claim needs a lot of work besides this issue. You are definitely in "hire an expert" territory.
Regarding the indefiniteness question, nobody can know this is not indefinite for sure unless there is a case where someone has fought for the right to claim things in this manner and won.
For example, Markush claims were not considered valid until someone called Markush had a meritorious case and paid to appeal their case sufficiently and won it. Now everyone can formulate a Markush claim if they want and have good chances to get it through (or at least it won't be rejected for the reason of reciting elements in the alternative).
However, as a practical matter, my impression is it will cost significantly less to pay the claim fees for an additional independent claim (only $96 for micro) than you will spend on attorney fees to appeal it properly. And in the latter case you might not even win.
So my advice is to stick to the beaten path when it comes to drafting claims. Follow the styles you see in many issued patents. Don't try to invent extra wheels in this field.

I don't quite understand. The wherein clause is pretty straight forward "wherein, any unidentified scores have a base value of zero.". Is this not a standard way to use a wherein clause? It merely defines a base case.

_Bear: Well, since you're the one claiming it's a "standard" way to use a wherein clause, perhaps you can produce links to a few issued patents that claim in this manner.

I am claiming it's standard. I am asking if it standard, based on the clear English meaning of what is stated in the wherein clause.

A partial answer.  Very confused. For example step e requires a third user who may not exist. Indefinite. Require the smallest number of users that allows the minimal novel, non-obvious invention. Let’s say that’s two. If someone uses your scheme with three or thirty three, they have inherently used two and infringe.
It seems odd that step b isn’t parallel to step a. I assume the second set is related to the second input identification. So there  might not be a third score but it’s zero? This could be restructured to make more sense if I understood what you are doing but don’t tell us.

there is no third user. e requires a third score.

In step b, the second score could be interpreted as a score for the system.

So in other words, just one total user is enough to infringe.

please revise your answer, thanks.

Way too confusing

This is just an example claim. The point is, I just need to know whether this claim can be rejected on indefiniteness caused by the optional step to identify a third score. I want to know whether the wherein clause suffices to make the third score well defined.
